# realtime data passed to callback is for wrong user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, callback, real-time

Realtime updates are kicking my ass!  I have my entire fb app working except for this one area and I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My app is approved using these permissions:

```
"scope" => "offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream,user_location,user_status",
```

Next, I subscribe using these settings:

```
$subscribe = array( 'access_token'=> substr($my_access_token,13),
                    'object' => 'user',
                    'fields' => 'name,feed',
                    'callback_url' => $fbconfig['callback'], 
                    'verify_token' => $fbconfig['secret']);
```

Via my app I post a status update on behaf of Bill Smith (userid: 000041143) and 
that appears on Bill Smith's wall just fine.  Next, using a an account for John 
Doe (userid: 000004842 which has NOT authorized my app) I comment on the status post
made on Bill Smith's wall and this triggers the callback but what I'm getting (see below)
is an entry telling me that John Doe's wall has changed and no mention of Bill Smiths
wall is ever made.

Here's the notification given in the callback:

```
updates = Array
(
  [object] => user
  [entry] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [uid] => 000004842
              [id] => 000004842
              [time] => 1325101631
              [changed_fields] => Array
                  (
                      [0] => feed
                  )

          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [uid] => 000004842
              [id] => 000004842
              [time] => 1325101651
              [changed_fields] => Array
                  (
                      [0] => feed
                  )

          )
    )
)
```

As you can see, this is not a notification that a comment has been made to Bill Smiths wall but that one has been made to John Doe's... I dont get this... I must be doing SOMETHING wrong!

Comment: I'm curious to find out what is the cause of this.  I've upvoted this question for you.  Hopefully someone knows the answer  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues before with photo IDs turning up 'wrong', the issue occurred because I was treating it as an INT but PHP was truncating it because it was too big, I had to treat it as a string. Could this be your issue perhaps?